# Convert enum to JSON String with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Im trying to convert an Enum class into a JSON string using jackson, the problem is the class is in a jar file so I am looking for better soultion then changing it.

when I use this code I get the following output:

**Code**

```java
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
BrainWave brainwave = BrainWave.DELTA;
brainwave.value(50);
System.out.println(ow.writeValueAsString(brainwave));
```

**Output**

```
"DELTA"
```

**The output I want:**

```json
{
  "type" : 1,
  "value" : 50
}
```

I know i can use @JsonFormat but As I stated before, I rather not change the jar file.

Comment: Define and register a custom `JsonSerializer` for the enum type. Note that enums should really not be mutable.

Answer (score -1):

Try a `StdDeserializer` - this article on [Enum Serialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums) shows the different ways but in your case you'll want something like this (this is a rewrite of their example at the bottom based on your snippet above)

```
public class DeltaEnumDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<DELTA> {

    @Override
    public Distance deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        final int type = node.get("type").asInt();
        final int value = node.get("value").asInt();

        for (final DELTA curr : DELTA.values()) {
            if (curr.type == type && curr.value == value) {
                return curr;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This article shows a snippet of code on [linking up the deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization). ie.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(DELTA.class, new DeltaEnumDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

DELTA readValue = mapper.readValue(json, DELTA.class);
```

Comment: Please add the critical part of those links to your answer so it remains useful when/if those links no longer work.